# Error about column literals using udf function on a dataframe with pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to use a udf function on a dataframe with pyspark but getting error about column literals and suggesting I use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.  I´m not clear how to do this.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def compareElem(elem):
    return elem[1]

def getSmallest(type, final_list):
  final_list.sort(key=compareElem)
  print(final_list)
  l = final_list[0][0]
  print('idx=', l)
  if type == 1:
    l = (((l/4)+1)*4)-1

  return l
```

Function works ok on List input

```
getSmallest(0, [ ( 0, 1), (1, 1.1), (2, 0.5) ])
```

returns

```
[(2, 0.5), (0, 1), (1, 1.1)] 
('idx=', 2)
```

But fails here used with udf and dataframe columns

```
func_udf = udf(getSmallest, IntegerType())

raw_dataset_df = raw_dataset_df.withColumn('result',func_udf( 
  raw_dataset_df['type'], [ ( 0, raw_dataset_df['Icorr_LBT01_R'] ), (1, raw_dataset_df['Icorr_LBT01_S']) ] ));
```

I get following error

```
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: [(0, Column<Icorr_LBT01_R>), (1, Column<Icorr_LBT01_S>)] of type <type 'list'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

Not sure what this means or how to fix.  I tried wrapping lit around each Column element but not clear what this should do and it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

any argument in your UDF should be a column. 
In your case `[ ( 0, raw_dataset_df['Icorr_LBT01_R'] ), (1, raw_dataset_df['Icorr_LBT01_S']) ]` is not a column, it is a list (python object) and you cannot use it in your udf.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply.  I just tried modifying to pass the column data only and the lit around my index values and I can make the list in the function.  All works great.  Thanks!

Comment: You can you fixed values with lit function.